# ExtJS 4 celleditor combobox return value

Tags: javascript, datagrid, combobox, extjs4

I'm looking how to solve this issue. What I have:

- Grid panel
- Cell renderer
- Cell editor – combobox

My renderer is:

```
renderer: function(value) {
    return value || "&mdash;";
}
```

So if `value` parameter is defined it'll be displayed, otherwise we'll display `–`.

Editor is:

```
editor: {
    xtype: "combobox",
    store: Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", { ... }),
    displayField: "name",
    valueField: "id",
    queryMode: "local"
}
```

And when editing is finished value from `valueField` will be returned and pushed into renderer as parameter, so I'll see entry's ID in the cell.

My problem is that I want to display value from `displayField` in the cell (push it into renderer), but `record` should contains entry's ID (`valueField` value).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If docs for [renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) are correct the third argument passed into `renderer` is `record`. You can modifie it (set 'ID') in `renderer`:

```
renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
  // value == valueField
  record.set('ID', value);

  var displayValue;
  // displayValue (corresponding to valueField) can be retrieved from combo's store:
  displayValue = combosStore.find('id', value).get('name');
  return displayValue || "&mdash;";
}
```

Comment: where is comboStore comming from?